# On Windows, how can I kill all processes having files open in a directory?

Tags: windows, powershell

One really frustrating "feature" of windows is that processes lock up files and prevent the removal of directories.

I'm looking for a way to locate all processes which have files open in that directory, something like "lsof" on unix. I'm looking for some powershell magic, and I'd rather not have to buy some custom maintenance tool.

Answer (score 7):

So I have good news and bad news. I'll start with the bad news... I haven't found a way to close locked files strictly within PowerShell. The good news is that it can be done with a PowerShell script, and a little help from a free utility from SysInternals called Handle.exe. Here's the script I have on hand to do this:

```psh
Function Close-LockedFile{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String[]]$Filename
)
Begin{
    $HandleApp = 'C:\sysinternals\Handle.exe'
    If(!(Test-Path $HandleApp)){Write-Host "Handle.exe not found at $HandleApp`nPlease download it from www.sysinternals.com and save it in the afore mentioned location.";break}
}
Process{
    $HandleOut = Invoke-Expression ($HandleApp+' '+$Filename)
    $Locks = $HandleOut |?{$_ -match "(.+?)\s+pid: (\d+?)\s+type: File\s+(\w+?): (.+)\s*$"}|%{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'AppName' = $Matches[1]
            'PID' = $Matches[2]
            'FileHandle' = $Matches[3]
            'FilePath' = $Matches[4]
        }
    }
    ForEach($Lock in $Locks){
        Invoke-Expression ($HandleApp + " -p " + $Lock.PID + " -c " + $Lock.FileHandle + " -y") | Out-Null
    If ( ! $LastexitCode ) { "Successfully closed " + $Lock.AppName + "'s lock on " + $Lock.FilePath}
    }
}
}
```

Now, if you want to do that for all files in a directory just get all the files, and run a ForEach loop on the file's `FullName` property. You should then be able to delete the directory without issues.

**Edit:** Here's the link to Handle.exe's web page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx (thanks to Kev because I was too lazy to look it up myself.. Thanks Kev!)

Comment: Don't forget to link to `handle.exe`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: The script actually refers the user to sysinternals.com if the executable isn't found. I figured people could find it on the site once they went there.

Comment: Fair do's, I didn't scroll far enough to the right, others might not read that text, as is so often the case these days.

Comment: I fear this might become a little slow if I have to test every file in a directory first - on the other hand I suppose I can attempt an "rd" and then just test those that are left over...